# How can I set user and password for Kafka server?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, apache-kafka

I'm beginner in Kafka Software. I wanna run Kafka in my server. I run it but I can't set password and all can connect to my server. How can I set password Kafka that no one can connect? I used Spring Boot.

---

### My current config...

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@SuppressWarnings("SpringFacetCodeInspection")
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {

        final Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);

    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {

        final Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 10);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);

    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    }

}
```

Comment: what's your kafka server version?

Answer (score 3):

in your application.yml:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: <ip>:<port>
    properties:
      security:
        protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      sasl:
        mechanism: PLAIN
        jaas:
          config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="my_user" password="my_password";
```

in config class:

```
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");
props.put("sasl.jaas.config", PlainLoginModule.class.getName() + " required username=\"" + my_user + "\" password=\"" + my_password + "\";")
```

## Update

in your `server.properties`:

> ```
> listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093,SASL_SSL://localhost:9094
> advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093,SASL_SSL://localhost:9094
> security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
> ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
> ssl.client.auth=required
> sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-512
> sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-512
> # Broker security settings
> ssl.truststore.location=
> <kafka-binary-dir>/config/truststore/kafka.truststore.jks
> ssl.truststore.password=password
> ssl.keystore.location=
> <kafka-binary-dir>/config/keystore/kafka.keystore.jks
> ssl.keystore.password=password
> ssl.key.password=password
> # ACLs
> authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
> super.users=User:admin
> ```

Comment: I add my current config to main post. How can I solve this problem via code config?

Comment: @MyName I edited the answer, use it to set password for the consumer. hope it'll be helpfull

Comment: OK. Thank. But how can I set password IN KAFKA? I run it via kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties where i need set pasword?

Comment: @MyName look at the update

Comment: not work - localhost/127.0.0.1 (Unexpected handshake request with client mechanism PLAIN, enabled mechanisms are [])

Comment: Your producer config has user `my_user `. I think the step missing is the creation of that user on the server. Would be something like this: `./bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=my_password]' --entity-type users --entity-name my_user`